# dojo1.8 - populate select 2 from select 1

Tags: dojo

Unable to populate card_Select from meter_Select.
I am using set method to set and store every time meter_Select is changed.

Please see my codes as below:-

```
var store = new Memory({
data:[
{id:'', label:"Choose one of the cards"},
{id:'testdata1970_05', label:"Mk7ABC Card"},
{id:'testdata1970_10', label:"Mk7CBC Card"},
{id:'testdata2060_03', label:"Mk10BC Card"},
]});

var memoStore1 = new ObjectStore({objectStore:store});
var meter_Select = new Select
        ({store:memoStore1,
        style:{width:'140px'},
        }, "node_meterSelect");
        meter_Select.startup();

var card_Select = new Select
({style:{position: 'absolute', margin: '20px', left:'60px', width:'140px'},
id:'cardSelect'
}, "node_cardSelect");

on(meter_Select, 'change', function(evt)
console.debug('Selected Card = '+ meter_Select.value);
request.post('listofcards.php',{data:{cardX : meter_Select.value},
handleAs:"json"}).then(

function(response)
{var memoStore2 = new Memory({data:response});//ok
console.debug("Loaded into memoStore2 ->" +memoStore2);

var combx = registry.byId('cardSelect');//ok to be undefined.
combx.set('store', memoStore2);
combx.set('value',"");
combx.set('placeHolder',"Choose one of the batch...");
combx.set('searchAttr', 'mfg_code');
combx.startup();
},//function(response)

function(error)//ok
    alert('Getting a list of cards = '+error);
}//function(error)
)//then.});//meter_Select.on
```

Any idea? 
Clement

Comment: Just realised that label must be used instead of value. But I still want to use Select. So how do I change in store that that value  can be replaced with  label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbjZ3/1/) the second select is populated from an Ajax request, that is triggered from the first.

The crux of it is in this function, where a new `ObjectStore` is created for the select, and the `setStore()` method is called to update the dijit:

```
    function onDataLoaded(response) {
        var memory = new Memory({
            data: response
        });
        var store = new ObjectStore({
            objectStore: memory
        });
        console.log("response", response, "store", store);

        var cardSelect = registry.byId('cardSelect');
        console.log(cardSelect);
        cardSelect.setStore(store);
    }
```